# Description of the SQL movie databse made by IMDBpy

Tags: mysql, imdb, imdbpy

Recently, I am using IMDBpy API to scrape the IMDB dataset. In this API, there is a imdbpy2sql.py which could convert IMDB movie dataset to a SQL database. 
But I can not find any description of this dataset. So I can not understand the schema of this SQL database. There are too many tables in this database. Is there any way to know that?

I strictly follow this website to build my database http://blog.secaserver.com/2013/08/importing-imdb-sample-data-set-mysql/.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt that there are too many tables. There are a lot properties/relationships available.

I generated [image: this image] once while creating [pyIRDG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyirdg/). You can have a look at that code too for documentation on the available data. Here is the output of the comments: http://pastebin.com/zGnZ02w4

I've also used [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to generate a schema from the db.

There is also this [German blog article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809163958/http://meolus.de/blog/imdb/entity-relationship-model-erm-zur-imdbpy-ausgabe/) with [image: an ERM image].

> not that I'm aware of, and for sure our db is not in any NF. :-)
>   Anyway, you can easily look at the scheme in the
>   imdb/parser/sql/dbschema.py module or using some tool directly on the
>   database.
>   [Source](https://sourceforge.net/p/imdbpy/mailman/message/30343394/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your carefulness!! It is exactly what I need. Did you ever use IMDbPY for movie information scraping?

Comment: No, I only used the provided IMDb datasets.

Comment: @ofthelit Very old subject but still got a question : basically the table aka_name looks a bit useless. What you reckon ?

Comment: Depends on your use case. It could be useful for having better matches when searching for people.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I've come across an question on this particular Diagram and want to know how to find all movies of a particular person/actor. I mean i just want the relevant tables for mentioned task. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use these tables: name, cast_info and title

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Comment: Glorfindel, what code are you referring to? 
The 'Source' link at the bottom refers to 'de bron' of the quote.